# C++ - cin is skipping input without any user input

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int userinput;
    int sums;
    int sum = 0;
    vector<int> nums;
    
    cout << "Enter as many numbers as you'd like." << endl;
    while (cin >> userinput) {
        nums.push_back(userinput);
    }
    
    cout << "Enter the numbers you want to add: ";
    cin >> sums;
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < sums; ++i) {
        sum += nums[i];
    }
    
    cout << "The sum of the first " << sums << " numbers is: " << sum << "." << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that on the line where I take input for the variable sums, whenever I actually run the code, this input line is skipped over and sums just gets set to 1 without any of my own input. I'm sorry if this is a really stupid question but I have nowhere else to ask as I am trying to learn myself.

I've tried cin.clear() because I've heard that could fix it but none of them worked.

Comment: The loop `while (cin >> userinput)` will only end when you send the end-of-file. That will set the `eofbit` state in the stream, and it will no longer be possible to read from it. You must `clear` that state *before* you next input. A possible other solution is to ask for `sums` *first*, then do the input for `nums`.

Comment: On another note, what happens if the user only inputs one number (or even none) for `nums`, and then enter a big number for `sums`? Please take some time to think about that.

Comment: I do not get how the user should stop inputting as many numbers as they want and then input how many to sum up. If I enter 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 and then want to enter 3 for sums, i.e. not as another number, how is that supposed to work? I.e. what makes you think "sums just gets set to 1 without any of my own input"? What is the value of `sums` before it gets set to 1?

Comment: If the `while (cin >> userinput)` loop ends, `cin` is in some error state.   Apart from the fact that the user needs to trigger that somehow (the approach is system dependent),  the error state needs to be cleared before attempting to read any subsequent input.

Comment: @Peter what i dont get is where exactly i would clear the error state.

Comment: @jnasdandas - If you have some value that cannot occur in the list, like `0`, or `-1`, or `99999`, you can use that as a signal and stop reading when it is input.

Comment: Consider telling a story to clarify your interface design. Maybe "The user sees 'Enter as many numbers as you like.' and starts repeatedly doing digit-typing and hitting the enter-key, until they do not want to enter more numbers. Then, in order to indicate that they are done with entering numbers, they do ....". Later "User sees 'Enter the numbers you want to add:' and responds by digit-typing the number of values they want to sum up followed by another use of the enter-key." Note that the part inbetween is what is unclear to me. I probably misunderstood, just set me right.

Comment: @Yunnosch basically the user inputs some numbers into a vector. Then the user can choose the first X numbers in the vector to add together. For example the vector contains 1, 2 ,3 , 4, 5 and the user inputs 3 into the variable sums, it should return 1+2+3. The issue is explained best by Peter above but basically I need to clear the input stream somewhere in the code which i dont know

Comment: "the user inputs some numbers into a vector". How? How does the user experience that? I ask because from point of view of the program, the user does not do anythign for ages after the first output. Then the user enters a single number. Then does not do anything for another eternity. And so on. Which means that program cannot tell when the user is done with entering as many numbers as they like and starts entering another number with a different meaning. Please tell a more detailed story - from users point of view. Which keys are involved? Thinking "I am done witht numbers." is CPU-invisible.

Comment: @Yunnosch you can use '|' or ctrl z on windows to terminate the while loop. Unfortunately this also puts the input into an error state that blocks input.  You need to clear this error state.

Comment: Cool. So from point of view of user (as intended but currently problematic): "see output 1, number, enter, number, enter, number, enter, number, enter. ctrl-z, see output 2, number enter". From point of view of program "output, start input loop, collect inputs into vector, input loop ends, cin is in error state (which causes the end of the loop); output, attempt to read another input; failure because of error state" is what you observe. And your question is when to do the error state clearing? Did I get that right?

Comment: moreso where i would put the error state clearing

Comment: By the way, you really need to check why the input loop ended, if it was because of EOF, or some error. If it was for some error, then report it and end the program. Otherwise clear the state and continue.

Comment: yeah it was just because of eof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that `while (cin >> userinput)` will be exited is if `cin` evaluates to `false`. `cin` evaluates to `false` only if it's in an error state, which would prevent any further operations using `cin`. You have to clear the error state with `cin.clear` **before** you ask for the next input from the user:

```
cout << "Enter the numbers you want to add: ";
cin.clear();
cin >> sums;
```

As the comments have said, it would be better if the user could input some value to signal to the program that they've stopped inputting numbers. For example:

```
while (cin >> userinput) {
   if (userinput == -1 /* or whatever value you want */) break;
   nums.push_back(userinput);
}
```

Breaking the loop this way allows the loop to be exited without setting `cin` to be in an error state (it's also arguably better design).